# Entity Framework not recognizing stored procedure, showing invalid object SQL error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have working code where I use EF to connect with my database. Recently the database has been moved to a different server. I started getting errors on few stored procedures from the EF `DBContext` ('Invalid object name');

I tried to look into the EDMX however can not make out any difference. There are a few stored procedures which run just fine, but another few do not.

```
public List<DTO_SRS_Roles_Result> AllRolesData()
{
    // Invalid object name 'aspnet_NPMS_DEV..Aspnet_Roles'.
    var query = (from a in ctx.ASPNET_Get_SRS_Roles()                       
                 select a).Distinct();
    List<DTO_SRS_Roles_Result> "lstRoles" = 
          new List<DTO_SRS_Roles_Result>();

    query.ToList().ForEach(rec =>
    {
        lstRoles.Add(new DTO_SRS_Roles_Result
        {
            RoleId = rec.RoleId,
            RoleName = rec.RoleName.TrimEnd().TrimStart().Trim()
         });
     });

    return lstRoles;
}
```

Procedure name is `ASPNET_Get_SRS_Roles`, but it says

> Invalid object name 'aspnet_NPMS_DEV..Aspnet_Roles'

What could be the reason?

Comment: sp permissions such as execute or different schema , aslo check ModelBrowser on sp name

Comment: 'Invalid object name 'aspnet_NPMS_DEV..Aspnet_Roles'  : There are two .. [dot-dot] characters there. Did you copy it like that or is that really in the error message?

Comment: @callisto it's there with error message. the message posted here is not edited.

Comment: @PowerMouse how to check ModelBrowser